# When do I require using __init__.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

I have the following structure:

```
/blog
    /app
        /static
            staticfile.py
        /templates
            templatefile.py
    run.py
```

In `run.py` I have,

```
from app.static import staticfile

print("you run me")
```

In `staticfile.py` I have, `print("ran from staticfile")`

When I run `python run.py` I get,

```
ran from staticfile
you run me
```

I do not have `__init__.py` anywhere and I do not have a virtual environment.  How does my reference work without the `__init__.py` file? Is it because I'm using Python 3.4? I am in Windows 7 if it matters.

EDIT:  Best I can tell it is because I am in 3.4.  I explicitly used `C:\python27\python run.py` and it failed until I put `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 2):

The 3.4 Glossary has this entry

> namespace package
>
> A PEP 420 package which serves only as a container for subpackages.
>   Namespace packages may have no physical representation, and
>   specifically are not like a regular package because they have no
>   **init**.py file.

From my reading of the PEP, directories contained in directories on `sys.path` but not containing `__init__.py` are potential namespace directories.  When `run.py` is run, `'.'`, representing `/blog`, is added to the front of `sys.path`.  Therefore, the directories in `/blog' are searched as potential namespace directories.

The PEP also says

> If a developer knows that her package will never be a portion of a
>   namespace package, then there is a performance advantage to it being a
>   regular package (with an **init**.py ).  Creation and loading of a regular 
>   package can take place immediately when it is located along the path.
>   With namespace packages, all entries in the path must be scanned
>   before the package is created.

In other words, every directory on `sys.path` is searched for possibly other modules in the `app.static` package, instead of stopping with `'.'` (`/blog`). I would go ahead and add the `__init__.py` files that you thought were required.

The PEP also noted the possible surprise effect.

> Note that an ImportWarning will no longer be raised for a directory
>   lacking an **init**.py file. Such a directory will now be imported as
>   a namespace package, whereas in prior Python versions an ImportWarning
>   would be raised.